# Thumbnail preview image default to Viewpoint instead of Camera

Tags: interface, camera, workflow, image

Is there a way to save a .blend file und generate the thumbnail from the image of the current viewport?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleting the camera will default to the viewport preview image.

This fixed the problem of not showing vertex colors in the preview image, too.